# Saving a line into a variable in a Windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want the 4th line from App.Config file. The below command gets me that.
I do not know how to save that line into a variable.
Can anyone give me the syntax for it?

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (App.Config) do echo %%i&goto nextline
:nextline
```

Comment: `set "foo=%%i" & goto nextline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set` command:

```
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (App.Config) do (
    set my_line=%%i 
    goto nextline 
)
:nextline
    echo %my_line%
```